# Stop EDMX generating a list of entities in one to many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I am using Database First on SQL Server and I have one to many relationship between **ServiceType** table and **EquipmentType** table. Both tables have a FK into **ServiceTypeEquipmentType** table where there is a record for each Equipment type and it's assigned one of the service types.

EquipmentType model generated by EDMX containes **List< ServiceTypeEquipmentType >** but since every equipment type has only **one** record in ServiceTypeEquipmentType table it would be very useful for me if the EDMX will add only a ServiceTypeEquipmentType as property, not a list of them.

Should I add some constraints on my tables or is there a EDMX property that I have to set in order to have a relationship of one-to-many and not many-to-many on the model generated by EDMX?

Now for retrieving the ServiceType of a Service I am doing something like:
**service.EquipmentType.ServiceTypeEquipmentTypes.First(x=>x.EquipmentTypeId==service.EquipmentTypeId).ServiceType**

I hope that there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Are the two foreign keys also the primary key of ServiceTypeEquipmentType?

Comment: No, ServiceTypeEquipmentType has Id (PK), EquipmentTypeId (FK) and ServiceTypeId (FK)